# Jenkins Agent JNLP Behind AWS NLB Connection Timout

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, nlb, jenkins-agent

I am trying to setup a Jenkins agent running on a Mac Mini that will connect to the Jenkins controller in AWS using JNLP. I have created a Network Load Balancer that listens on port 50000 and forwards the traffic to the Master instance. The security group attached to the Master instance allows for traffic from the public IP of the mac mini. On the node configuration I specified the tunnel connection with the DNS name of the NLB.

While trying to connect I receive an IO Exception that the Operation timed out. When I run TCP Dump on the master instance I can see traffic coming from the mac mini to the Master instance.

If I connect the mac mini with a vpn connection I can connect skipping the NLB, so I believe something is wrong with how I setup the NLB. Is there a way to change the connection timeout to increase it, or set the TCP keepalive interfal?

Comment: Can you try using netcat to see if the port is accessible by direct IP?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?